# Insert birthdate to databse from day, month, year dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my form I have three separate dropdown lists for birthday: Day, Month, and Year.
In my database, I have a column "birthday" with type date.

How will I convert those values from the dropdownlists in a specific date format to be accepted in the database?

Dropdown list values:

```
Day       Month         Year

1          Jan          1990
2          Feb          1991
3          Mar          1992
```

...and so on.

I tried this. It works but I know there's a better way:

```
DateTime bday = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dropDay.SelectedValue, dropMonth.SelectedValue, dropYear.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: are u taking the value from a single dropdown or 3 diffrent dropdowns

Comment: 3 different dropdowns

Comment: I need it to be formatted in date mm/dd/yyyy as the final output

Comment: the values need to be "combined" and be converted to date datatype

Comment: y cant u directly use a datepicker? its best u can everything together and space saved in UI

Comment: sorry but it's the requrement

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DateTime` and initilize it like this:

```
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(int year, int month, int day);
```

Comment: what data type does that specific constructor accept? take note, month is string in my dropdown list

Comment: this constructor accept int, so if you have only Month on string maybe you can create a switch for parse it to int

Comment: @ejmtv make the "value" of your dropdown options be the month number, and only the displayed text be the name (as string)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse your Month string to int and than you should use `DateTime` and initialize it like this (as AitorFDK wrote) :

```
int month = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(int year, int month, int day);
```